How to install 'tlmgr' in alpine linux (LaTex)
How can i install tlmgr in alpine linux.
I have installed the package
[texlive-full](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/texlive-full)

Where is that package? located?
The location where i can find the binary of the 'tlmgr'. What package do i have to install in alpine for getting this to work.
I ran go this error before and i need the package manger named tlmgr to install the package called 'graphicx' in the tlmgr package manger.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Alpine Linux) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./index.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \usepackage
               {graphicx} % For including images
? q
OK, entering \batchmode%


Try to compile with pdflatex, not pdftex

[name@computer_name ~/FOLDER_NAME]$ pdflatex index.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Alpine Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./index.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
! LaTeX Error: \usepackage before \documentclass.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
...
l.1 \usepackage{
graphicx} % For including images
?

You need to first load a class, then the packages

Try this test document: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
content...
\end{document}`

Thanks that worked. But still where is the binary for 'tlmgr' in alpine?

If you want to use tlmgr, don't use the linux package of texlive, but install texlive from tug.org

So you are saying that Alpine Linux did not include tlmgr in their repo?
